# Can I test GTM Datalayer(goole tag manager) by adding data to datalayer through console

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have added data to datalyer through console.but the same is not getting relfected under datalayer tab  under google tag assistant extension in chrome

I tried
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'new_subscriber',
'formLocation': 'footer'
});

but datalayer not updating in tag assistant. how to verify if this is working as i dont have access to the gtm portal

Comment: Could you please provide relevant code samples, expected and actual results.

Comment: i have updated. i  used datalayer.push through console. the datalayer object is getting filled with data when queried through console. but the same is not getting reflected in tag assistant

Answer (score 0):

The Datalayer is only an array.

Easiest way to check is just console the datalayer.

If you want to check is the GTM also listened.

You can install the following extensions:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dataslayer/ikbablmmjldhamhcldjjigniffkkjgpo

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtmga-debug/ilnpmccnfdjdjjikgkefkcegefikecdc

Comment: Dataslayer(extension) is recording my pushes to datalayer. but google tag assistant is not. Is it okay?

Comment: From my test with my own GTM. The Tag Assistant will not update if I push new event to datalayer. If you want to check the GTM is listening the datalayer event you push.
You can create a new GTM with your google account and inject it from chrome devtool . With debug mode on, you can see the datalayer status. The origin GTM should have same result with yours.

Comment: Thank you  Darrellwan .One more question, i am unable to see any network calls when i push items to datalayer. how does this data gets transferred to google

Comment: It should be treated as 3 part. The datalayer, the GTM and GA. Datalayer is a data level array which tell GTM which event is firing (Trigger). The GTM need another setting to send data to GA when the event fired (Tag). Once the GTM owner set the proper setting with your datalayer event. You should be able to see the GA hit in your network.

Comment: okay.. so once the gtm setup is done properly, data will be sent automatically. I hope my understanding is correct